# three.js: Render 2d projection

Tags: three.js

I want to render a cube similar to [image: this one].

My problem is how to render the face projections.

I tried using Reflector, but it is tricky to size and position so it captures just the face that I want, and also shows the sides.

I also saw I can use a separate canvas to render (I imagine using an orthographic camera), but I wish for everything to be in the same canvas. I saw an example with multiple views, but it seems that they can't be positioned behind.

So, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach to solve the issue:

Setup an orthographic camera such that its frustum encloses the cube. You can then position the camera in front of each side of the cube, use `lookAt( cube.position )` to orient it properly and then render the scene into a render target. You need one render target per side. You can then use it as a texture for the respective plane mesh.

There is an official live example that demonstrates how RTT (render-to-texture) is done with `three.js`. Try to use it as a code template for your own app.

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_rtt

Comment: I'll look at it, can you point me to how to setup the camera so that its frustum encloses the cube?

Comment: For starters I would do this manually. Assuming the camera is positioned at the center of the cube's sides, the `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` properties can be derived from the cube's size.

Comment: So, I put a plane geometry to the left of the cube (in the image above it is where the blue center is), added to the scene, and then did the RTT with a virtual camera and the scene. I get the error "glDrawElements: Source and destination textures of the draw are the same.".  I understand this is because now when the canvas is rendered, it reads the texture I put in the plane (right?) but I don't understand how Reflector doesn't have this problem

Comment: When you perform the RTT call, set `visible` of the plane mesh to `false`. It's not possible to render into a render target and use it as a texture in the same render call. When `Reflector` renders the scene, it makes itself invisible, too (see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/44639b58eaac4fde6f91b6065c6e0519d86350a9/examples/jsm/objects/Reflector.js#L154).